# What's the proper way to call an Oracle stored procedure from a Liquibase changelog in Groovy format?

Tags: oracle, grails, groovy, liquibase

I'm having trouble executing an Oracle stored procedure from a Groovy-format change log.  Executing the very same stored procedure from an XML-format changelog works fine.

In both cases, the `dbm-update` call completes successfully with no warnings or errors.  I am able to see the entries in the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table, so Liquibase definitely thinks it is running the change set.

However, when using the Groovy format, the stored procedure is not actually called.  This stored procedure happens to log information (user, timestamp, etc.) every time it is executed.  The log entries are present every time the procedure is called from an XML-format change log but missing every time the procedure is called from a Groovy-format change log.

What's the proper way to call a stored procedure when using Groovy-format change logs?

Here's my working `changelog.groovy`.  Note that I've removed all of the other include statements for simplicity, and that I've commented out the Groovy version of the include that does not work.

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    include file: "schema-grants.xml"
    //include file: "schema-grants.groovy"
}
```

Here's the `schema-grants.xml`.  Note that I've removed the schema/namespace information for brevity.

```
<databaseChangeLog ...>
    <changeSet id="schema-grants" author="jstricker" runAlways="true">
        <sql>call meta.grants_pkg.schema_grants('PARAMETER_VAL');</sql>
        <rollback/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

And finally, here's the `schema-grants.groovy`:

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(id: "schema-grants", author: "jstricker", runAlways: "true") {
        sql {
            "call meta.grants_pkg.schema_grants('PARAMETER_VAL');"
        }
        rollback {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect this is a bug, so I've entered https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION-179.  If the team accepts the bug, I'll add an answer here.